# Does this view control use on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, controls

[image]

This screen is iBooks app on my iPhone.
And you can see the view control like segmented control(it has features like popover control on iPad).

What is this view control's name?
Do I use this view control? (I'm an external developer.) In other word.. Is this view control public APIs?

Thank you for your reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html)!

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link : 
[PopTipView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=popup)

[Similar To PopTipView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/zpopovercontroller)